# How do I make chrome console behave consistantly

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

**Issue** - When executing xpath expression in chrome console sometimes its successful in finding what I'm looking for and sometimes not. Not sure why it only works sporadically.

**Xpath expression**:$x('//button[@aria-label = "Next"]')

**Example HTML in which Im searching**:

```
<button aria-label="Next" id="ember157" class="artdeco-pagination__button artdeco-pagination__button--next artdeco-button artdeco-button--muted artdeco-button--icon-right artdeco-button--1 artdeco-button--tertiary ember-view" type="button">  <li-icon aria-hidden="true" type="chevron-right-icon" class="artdeco-button__icon" size="small"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="mercado-match" data-supported-dps="16x16" fill="currentColor" width="16" height="16" focusable="false">
  <path d="M5 15l4.61-7L5 1h2.39L12 8l-4.61 7z"></path>
</svg></li-icon><span class="artdeco-button__text">
    Next
</span></button>
```

Comment: I doubt it is a console issue but rather the element is being modified or added/removed. Can you confirm visually the element is always present and the label text is consistent?

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question so quickly.

Comment: And yes I verified "visually the element is always present and the label text is consistent". Thanks again.